# Specific Subsequences Converging to Same Value?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]An image of an analysis question from my homework is posted below. I've solved everything except for part c, where I've developed a general plan of attack:
1.) Prove that the even and odd subsequences must converge to the same value L.
2.) Prove that if all subsequences converge to the same value, the sequence must converge to the same value. 
Fin.) Therefore, the sequence converges and is Cauchy.

I'm having enormous amounts of trouble trying to prove 1. I've tried to prove it by assuming that they converge to different limits and showing that they then must overlap, which is a contradiction, but I have no answer for the case in which the limit of the even subsequence is lower than that of the odd subsequence.

Comment: There's no image.

Comment: My bad, completely slipped on that. Image is there now.